# Css selecting image with changing href value?

Tags: css

Please refer to this image code:

```
<img class="logoimage" src="logo.png?6270707261906064847" onmouseover="/logo_hover_2x.png?6270707261906064847'" onmouseout="this.src='logo_2x.png?6270707261906064847'" alt="Dear Leader">
```

I am trying to select each specific image using css so i can control the size.

I tried this already:

```
.logoimage[src$="logo_2x.png"] { //*CSS }
```

I cannot seem to select the image because the src is changing ?xxxxxx.

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$=` selector is for items ending with the specified attr. You want `.logoimage[src*="logo_2x.png"]` (which will match any `.logoimage` with that substring in the src)

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings